# arquillian jboss as7 managed and jacoco - jacoco.exec file is empty

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-arquillian, jacoco

I have a project that deploys on jboss 7.1.3 and uses arquillian for testing, and i'm trying to add code-coverage metrics to it.

im working with the managed container option (jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed) and for now i've just tried adding a -javaagent parameter to the jvm arguments that arquillian uses to start jboss, so my arquillian.xml looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">
    <defaultProtocol type="Servlet 3.0"/>

    <engine>
        <property name="deploymentExportPath">/tmp</property>
    </engine>

    <container qualifier="jboss"  default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="outputToConsole">true</property>
            <property name="jbossHome">[jboss home]</property>
            <property name="javaHome">[java home]</property>
            <property name="javaVmArguments">-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djboss.server.log.dir=logs -javaagent:[profile]\.m2\repository\org\jacoco\org.jacoco.agent\0.6.2.201302030002\org.jacoco.agent-0.6.2.201302030002-runtime.jar=destfile=C:\jacoco.exec,includes=*,excludes=,append=true,output=file,classdumpdir=classdumpdir,dumponexit=true</property>
            <property name="startupTimeoutInSeconds">120</property>
            <property name="allowConnectingToRunningServer">true</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>
```

im 100% certain that this argument is being picked up, since both the jacoco.exec file and the classdumpdir are created.

the problem is that the jacoco.exec file is empty. jboss is started, the tests are run and complete successfully, jboss is shut down, the classdumpdir is populated (so according to jacoco specs it means its finding my classes properly) but jacoco.exec remains completely empty.

if i provide the exact save `javaagent` argument to the exact same jboss that i start manually myself everything works fine.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you configure the jacoco extension? See here: https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-jacoco/blob/master/src/test/resources/arquillian.xml I would at least list the extension, without include exclude.

Comment: @JohnAment - tried adding <extension qualifier="jacoco"></extension> to my arquillian xml - didnt make any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, the issue was that jacoco only dumps the file contents when the jvm shuts down (it registers a hook for it), and apparently arquillian (at least the version im using?) doesnt shut the jvm down as nicely.

i ended up adding the following method to my test classes:

```
@After
public void writeOutJacocoData() {
    try {
        Class rtClass = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getParent().loadClass("org.jacoco.agent.rt.RT");
        Object jacocoAgent = rtClass.getMethod("getAgent", null).invoke(null);
        Method dumpMethod = jacocoAgent.getClass().getMethod("dump", boolean.class);
        dumpMethod.invoke(jacocoAgent, false);
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        logger.debug("no jacoco agent attached to this jvm");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("while trying to dump jacoco data",e);
    }
}
```

its ugly and brutish (and uses jacoco classes which they dont publish in any publically-available jacoco artifacts, hence the reflection) but works.

Comment: What version of arquillian are you using?

Comment: Seems like something else is wrong with your setup.  This doesn't happen for me.

Comment: @JohnAment - up until this my setup has been running hours-long arquillian tests dozens of time a day on multiple machines for months. if you have any piece of conf you'd like me to post i'd love to.

Comment: I have a project that needs the same steps like yours. I tried your method @After, but I get an exception at the first line, it doesn't find the class org.jacoco.agent.rt.RT. What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: @FlorinVistig - the latest jacoco 0.7.5 still contains the agent class under that name. im guessing your classloader structure is different than the setup i had. unfortunately i cant really help you with that.